# how to provide variable dynamic value from other template?

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
    <xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:variable name="first">
                         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list,' ')"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$first"/>
</xsl:template>
```

```
           <xsl:variable name="test">c0 c1 c2 c3 c4</xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="var2>
                  <xsl:call-template name="split">
                        <xsl:with-param name="returnvalue">
                             <xsl:value-of select="$test"></xsl:with-param>
                  </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:variable>
```

// processing done

i want to return value from template as c0 then back to template match do processing then again go to split template again return c1 done same processing then back to split template then again processing in match template; depending upon the value of test variable...

How could i retreive these values one by one and process the code..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet will scan forward over your input string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="string" select="'c0 c1 c2 c3 c4'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delim" select="' '"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="wrapper">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="wrapper">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- handle empty input -->
            <xsl:when test=" $string = '' "/>

            <!-- handle next token -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, $delim)">
                <xsl:call-template name="process">
                    <xsl:with-param name="substring" select="substring-before($string,$delim)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="wrapper">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,$delim)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- handle last token -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="process">
                    <xsl:with-param name="substring" select="$string"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="process">
        <xsl:param name="substring"/>
        <xsl:text>RECEIVED SUBSTRING: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$substring"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x000A;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce the following output:

```
RECEIVED SUBSTRING: c0
RECEIVED SUBSTRING: c1
RECEIVED SUBSTRING: c2
RECEIVED SUBSTRING: c3
RECEIVED SUBSTRING: c4
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but i want firstly i fetch c0 then process some code then c1 process same code and so on.

Comment: You ought to be able to replace `<xsl:template name="process">` with something more useful that will do your per-item processing, but I'm not clear on the rest of your requirements.